# jQuery this cycling

Tags: jquery, this

I want to count availability of specific items in my system (for example there is item 1 available 3 times, item 2 6 times etc.).

When item is added, its availability decrease by 1 when it's removed **it should** availability increase by one.

But using this code it repeats the function multiple times. I pressume, that the problem is in usage of `$(this)`, but I'm not sure:

```
$('.box .rm-this').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  removeBox($(this));
  $('.boxes_add #' + $(this).attr('id') + ' .amount').html(parseInt($('.boxes_add #' + $(this).attr('id') + ' .amount').text())+1);
});
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What does `removeBox` do?

Comment: Every 'box' has a remove button, which is used to remove the box. Its basically `$(this).parent().remove()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.html(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) can be used to updated the text in correct context.

```
$('.box .rm-this').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Use the method to update the text of element in correct context
    $(this).find('.amount').html(function(_, oldhtml){
        return parseInt(oldhtml, 10) + 1; //OR parseInt($(this).text(), 10) + 1;
    });

    //Move remove logic to the end
    removeBox($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was elsewhere, I had this click event in a function which was loaded everytime when new box was added. Thanks @Satpal for cleaning my code, which i modified only slightly:

```
$('.box .rm-this').off('click').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('#' + this.id).find('.amount').html(function(_, oldhtml){
      return parseInt(oldhtml, 10) + 1; 
  });

  removeBox($(this));
});
```